# How to Save Filter values on processing page

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom processing page that has 3 fields in the custom filter DAC.  I want any values in these three filter fields to stay set after the user clicks Process or Process All.  Right now, they are cleared out when the processing completes.  How can I get them to keep their value?

The filter DAC is currently unbound - should I make it a real table in the DB?

Here are what the views look like now:

```
    public PXFilter<POLineFilter> Filter;

    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<POLine, POLineFilter, 
        InnerJoin<PMProject, On<PMProject.contractID, Equal<POLine.projectID>>>,
        Where<POLine.closed.IsEqual<False>.And<POLine.cancelled.IsEqual<False>>
            .And<POLine.projectID.IsEqual<POLineFilter.projectID.FromCurrent>.Or<POLineFilter.projectID.FromCurrent.IsNull>>
            .And<POLine.orderNbr.IsEqual<POLineFilter.poNbr.FromCurrent>.Or<POLineFilter.poNbr.FromCurrent.IsNull>>
            .And<PMProject.ownerID.IsEqual<POLineFilter.projectManager.FromCurrent>.Or<POLineFilter.projectManager.FromCurrent.IsNull>>>> POLines;
```

TIA!

Comment: It's definitely not the unbound/bound status that is the issue, can you post your views?

Comment: You will need to change the PXFilter select to PXSelect and make sure that you have a Save action which you need to trigger from the Process Actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following as your 2nd view.

> `public PXCancel<POLineFilter> Cancel;`